# How to write to a /proc kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

How can I get data when a user writes to proc? (Ie: echo "foo" > /proc/myproc)

I've seen reading from proc (ie user does a "cat /proc/myproc") as detailed from this site: http://www.linux.com/learn/linux-training/39972-kernel-debugging-with-proc-qsequenceq-files-part-2-of-3

That seems to work well enough, but I haven't seen the analogous method for writing. Also, I have checked out TLDP, but their article seems way out of date: http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x769.html

Comment: i think now proc has been already considered as an old way. maybe you are more interested in sysfs.

Comment: look at LDD3 in the tag-wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/linux-kernel/info stuff is actually covered there.

Comment: I'm game for learning sysfs. Can you recommend any good tutorials/links, other than what Alex provided?

Comment: @Maxthecat : I'd recommend endyptula challenge for learning linux kernel dev, even if answers are sometimes really long to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the kernel API for dealing with `/proc` and `/sys` may vary between different kernel versions. Good news is that kernel itself is quite self explanatory. Means you can easily find an example of code just exploring sources. Just look for some file in `/proc` which supports write operation:

```
$ ls -l /proc | grep w
```

For example `sysrq-trigger` does:

```
--w-------  1 root root  0 Mar 12 00:41 sysrq-trigger
```

Then find the corresponding string in kernel sources:

```
$ find . -name '*.[ch]' -exec grep -Hn '"sysrq-trigger"' {} \;
```

Which gives you:

```
drivers/tty/sysrq.c:1105:   if (!proc_create("sysrq-trigger", S_IWUSR, NULL,
```

Now look into code in found file (look [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/sysrq.c?v=3.18#L1080) for version 3.18):

```
static ssize_t write_sysrq_trigger(struct file *file, const char __user *buf,
                                   size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
        if (count) {
                char c;

                if (get_user(c, buf))
                        return -EFAULT;
                __handle_sysrq(c, false);
        }

        return count;
}

static const struct file_operations proc_sysrq_trigger_operations = {
        .write          = write_sysrq_trigger,
        .llseek         = noop_llseek,
};

static void sysrq_init_procfs(void)
{
        if (!proc_create("sysrq-trigger", S_IWUSR, NULL,
                         &proc_sysrq_trigger_operations))
                pr_err("Failed to register proc interface\n");
}
```

The same you can do for some `sysfs` file. For faster search use some code indexer (like `cscope` for vim, or built-in code indexer in Eclipse).

Comment: What?! Read the sources?! What kind of nonsense is this?! :) Great idea